# Valor devuelto en un request.body [Object: null prototype] { '{"user_id":10}': '' }

Tags: nodejs, angular, express, http, sequelize.js

Hola y muy buenos días,

Estoy trabajando en la parte front-end en angular para una pagina web. tras logearse con un usuario tengo en un json el ID del usuario logeado asi que:

1) He creado un modelo en models/user.ts

```
export class User {
    user_id: string;
}
```

2) La función del componente components/myNovels.ts

```
const user = new User();
  user.user_id = (Este digito lo obtiene correctmanete de un JWT decodificado por ejemplo id: 10)

  this._ns.getUserNovelData(jwt, user).subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.usuario_novela = data.novelas;
    console.log(this.usuario_novela);
  });
```

3) Mi funcion en el servicio que hace la consulta a la BBDD: services/app.service.ts

```
 getUserNovelData(jwt: string, user: User): Observable<any> {

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': jwt
      })
    };

    const url = `${ this.urlnovelsdb }/api/novelas-usuario`;
    return this.http.post(url, user, httpOptions);
  }
```

4) Finalmente mi back-end tiene:

```
function getUserNovel(req, res) {
    var id = req.body;
    console.log(id);  // devuelve [Object: null prototype] { '{"user_id":10}': '' }
    novelas.sequelize.query('Aqui va una mega ultra Select').then(novelas => {
        res.status(200).send({ novelas })
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Ocurrio un erro al buscar la novela' })
    });
}
```

Mi problema es precisamente que no tengo ni idea de por que mi var id = req.body; esta recibiendo un `[Object: null prototype] { '{"user_id":10}': '' }`

No tengo ni idea de como recibir apropiadamente lo que esta mandando mi front-end al back-end para que lea el id: 10

Apreciare muchisimo su ayuda

Gracias!

Comment: Aquí estás recibiendo un Objeto: `user: User`, como parámetro de tu servicio. Luego, aquí lo pasas crudo: `this.http.post(url, user, httpOptions);`, cuando deberías enviar solo el `id`, intenta hacer algo así: `this.http.post(url, user.user_id, httpOptions);`. Prueba y comentas. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que estás mandando JSON pero le dices que no es JSON, sino que el formato es `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`. Quita ese encabezado de la petición y debería funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Jajaja no me lo creo, dos días matándome la cabeza. Ha sido eso ya funciona perfecto. te debo una cerveza.

Comment: Estos errores son los más complicados de ver porque no es el código en sí, sino la configuración del mismo, lo que los producen. Todos hemos pasado por esa frustración ;-)